# How to ignore product in cart total

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

In my eCommerce project I have to add some "external product" to my cart.
I have to write the external product price in the cart product listing (/checkout/cart/),
but this price should not being add to cart total price.

And, also, in the next step, customer should not see external product.
Same things in Sales administration.

How Can I do that ?
I already try to modify Checkout's module without any success.

Answer (score 0):

How you know what product you should add or ignore??
You can make a model extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product and overrides method getPrice, and there you can control what product you get the price and what you get 0.00.
IMO you should do one model to configure what product is no-price, and in the getPrice you search on this Module.

Comment: "How you know what product you should add or ignore??"
I have a field that I set to 1 (if I want to ignore, or 0 if I don't)

Comment: so just do that what i said and in your methods getPrice you do if($_product->getFieldCustom() == 'x') return $value, else return 0.00. simple